# How do I create multiple instances of python application server?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nginx, application-server

How do I create multiple instances of python application server?

I created an application server in python using httpserver. I am not using any python frameworks. Now I want to create multiple instances of the server and use load balancer on top of it. How can I create multiple instances of this application server? Are there any tutorials on how to create multiple instances?

I was going through Nginx. Can nginx create multiple instances? Are there any tutorials?

Details: I am working on windows machine. It is a python application server created using BaseHTTPServer. I am not using any framework like tornado, django.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind different ports for each instance of your server.

Make your script initialize each instance binding a different port ( e.g port 3000, 3001, 3002 ...) and configure nginx to spread the load on those ports.

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html , the example given is :

```
def run(server_class=BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer,
    handler_class=BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    server_address = ('', 8000)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

So you might create a class with a function like this as a method which could take the server port as an argument, in the example above the port is hard coded as 8000.